# How to get metadatas of soap service which require log in?

Tags: wcf, soap, metadata, svcutil.exe

I am trying to get metadatas of a service which require log in with svcutil.exe.
How can i do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are basically three ways to accomplish this:

1) Use Visual Studio "Add Service Reference" it will ask you for credentials.

2) Browse to WSDL in IE (after passing your credentials) and save off all WSDLs and XSDs then generate your Proxy using SVCUTIL from those.  Pain in the rear b/c it requires manual edits.

3) Obtain the proxy from the Service Provider.  They should have them generated and ready for you.

The strange thing is that the provider should have an exposed http endpoint w/o security that is available for you to generate your proxy from, as the first two of these aren't that user friendly depending on environment (firewalls, security settings, etc.).  Worst case they should be able to provide you WSDL to generate your proxy from.

Comment: i tried but it didn't get anything.It says "can not obtain from https"

Comment: You can see the wsdl if you go to IE, right? After you logon.  Also, have you tried to Add Service Reference in Visual Studio?

Comment: when i test in browser it writes "directory listing denied" also link contain https

Comment: If you cannot see the wsdl, then you will never be able to generate a proxy from it.  Who is the provider of said service?

Comment: i have username and ıd but i don't know how to log in with it without metadatas . I have tried this one https:\\username:password@example.com for log in but result was same. I tried add service referance but it couldn't resolve it too .

Comment: There is nothing you can do if you cannot see the wsdl. You should talk to the service provider and get help.  good luck.

Comment: Below code describe how to log on on their document so is it still possible to log in with this knowledge ? 
UserLogOn
Description: Is used to log in into ordering system.
Definition: UserLogOn(string username, string password)
Return structure: public struct MySession
{
public int UserID;
public string SessionID;
public int error;
};

Comment: What this looks like is an actual logon request once you are ready to use the Web Service.  Not the information to logon to get the WSDL / proxy generation.  Also, this doesn't look like a WCF service, not that it matters.  Just FYI.

Comment: So please tell me where i am doing mistake.Someone who has no technical knowledge about programing gave me all documents ,username and password.But when i check the pdf document there is only 2 service link and both is same . I can not see see anything on pages.Am i missing another else ?

Comment: Finally i encounter log on link on document. Thanks for your help and effort